# $\frac{I}{[0 \sim 1]} $ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^1$.

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

Let $I=[0,1]$ and the equivalence relation $\sim$ that identifies points $0$ and $1$.

I used this theorem :

$\textbf{Theorem:}$ Let $g: X \rightarrow Z$ continuous and surjective. Consider the equivalence relation in $X: x\sim y \Leftrightarrow f(x)=f(y)$ and consider the quotient topology in $\dfrac{X}{\sim}$. Then $q$ induces a bijective continuous function $f: \frac{X}{\sim} \rightarrow Z$  such that

- $f$ is homeomorphism $\Leftrightarrow$ $g$ is a quotient map.

$\textbf{My attempt:}$

Consider $g: I \rightarrow \mathbb{S}^1$ where $g(t)=(\text{cos}(2\pi t), \text{sin}(2 \pi t))$. Is continuos and surjective, by theorem the function

$$ f: \dfrac{I}{\sim} \rightarrow \mathbb{S}^1 $$

defined by $f([x])=(\text{cos}(2\pi x), \text{sin}(2 \pi x))$ is a continuous and bijective function. 
To see that it is a homeomorphism it would be enough to see that g is a quotient application (or that it is open or closed). Any hint?

Answer (score 1):

You can consider the map

$exp : \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{S}^1$

Such that $exp(t)=(cos(2\pi t), sin(2\pi t))=e^{2\pi it}$. This map is a covering map, so it is open. In other words it is the quotient induced by the action of $\mathbb{Z}$ on $\mathbb{R}$.

Your map is the restriction of this map on $I/\sim$, and so it is open.